# fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer

Tags: git, git-clone

Can some one help me to get rid of following:

```
vijay13@ubuntu:~$ git clone git://anongit.kde.org/plasma-mediacenter

Cloning into 'plasma-mediacenter'...

fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer
```

And

```
vijay13@ubuntu:~$ git clone git@git.kde.org:plasma-mediacenter

Cloning into 'plasma-mediacenter'...

Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How to get rid of both above issues?

Answer (score 33):

If internet connection is also fine, just run

```
git gc
```

and try again. It cleans up unnecessary files and optimize the local repository. For more details: [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)

Comment: Could you explain what this is doing and why it works?

Comment: "[gc] Runs a number of housekeeping tasks within the current repository, such as compressing file revisions (to reduce disk space and increase performance) and removing unreachable objects which may have been created from prior invocations of git add." -https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Surprisingly also worked for me! (This was after I returned to using an old machine of mine at work.)

Comment: I'm assuming you guys just ran it on the remote?

Answer (score 21):

I also have faced with this problem.

The problem is solved when i replace **"git://"** with **"https://"**

```
root@ubuntu:~# git clone git://github.com/osrg/ryu.git
Cloning into 'ryu'...
fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer

root@ubuntu:~# git clone https://github.com/osrg/ryu.git
Cloning into 'ryu'...
remote: Counting objects: 25613, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Receiving objects:  37% (9609/25613), 18.68 MiB | 60.00 KiB/s
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to outdated git dependency library. Try updating **curl** for your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue

```
vijay13@ubuntu:~$ git clone git://anongit.kde.org/plasma-mediacenter

Cloning into 'plasma-mediacenter'...

fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer
```

Here you are trying to check out a code by using the above command. 
I even encounter this error : Connection reset by peer when try to check out a code.

It is a problem with your **internet connection**.

Check your internet connection and try again.

It helped me.

Answer (score -1):

This can also be an issue when deleting repos (but not permanently). Make sure the repo is deleted in the trash/ recycling bin before cloning.

Alternatively press SHIFT + DEL to delete a folder/ file permanently.