# Why does git clone with git protocal from gitlab.com is not working?

Tags: git, gitlab

I've just created a public test project in https://gitlab.com/zchrissirhcz/justtest .
When clone it to local:

```
// this not working
git clone git://gitlab.com/zchrissirhcz/justtest
```

```
// but this working
git clone git@gitlab.com:zchrissirhcz/justtest.git

Cloning into 'justtest'...
fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer
```

I've also tried git clone with git protocal from github, and it just works:

```
git clone git://github.com/zchrissirhcz/pixel
```

Why does gitlab.com not support git clone with `git://` for public repo?

Comment: What happens when you use `ssh -T git@gitlab.com`?

Comment: @dan1st It shows "Welcome to GitLab, @zchrissirhcz!"

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: Does one of [thede answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17977206/10871900) help?

Comment: @dan1st I'm using Linux.  ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @dan1st Thank you for mention that SO page. Replace git:// with https:// solves the temporary problem but not explain why it is not valid to use.  Ok, seems not very necessary to figure out this, now I switch to https://.

Comment: `Why does gitlab.com not support git clone with git:// for public repo?` Ask on gitlab, not here. This is not a programming question. And you should be able to configure git protocol in your gitlab instance.

Comment: It could also be the case that ssh is blocked for this specific repository.