# AzureDevOps Self Hosted Git TCP Connection Reset

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am using AzureDevOps Self Hosted Linux Agent. I have used Azure Pipelines Github App to create the pipeline.

The agent is active but the job fails at Git Checkout step stating:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/Azure_agent/myagent/_work/4/s/.git/
git remote add origin https://github.com/org
git config gc.auto 0
git config --get-all http.https://github.com/org.extraheader
git config --get-all http.extraheader
git config --get-regexp .*extraheader
git config --get-all http.proxy
git config http.version HTTP/1.1
git --config-env=http.extraheader=env_var_http.extraheader fetch --force --tags --prune --prune-tags --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin --depth=1 +a8316d8395ac357bc5708fa00cf81730b1469180:refs/remotes/origin/a8316d8395ac357bc5708fa00cf81730b1469180
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/org/': TCP connection reset by peer
##[warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 8.926 seconds before retry.
git --config-env=http.extraheader=env_var_http.extraheader fetch --force --tags --prune --prune-tags --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin --depth=1 +a8316d8395ac357bc5708fa00cf81730b1469180:refs/remotes/origin/a8316d8395ac357bc5708fa00cf81730b1469180
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/org/': TCP connection reset by peer
##[warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 1.213 seconds before retry.
git --config-env=http.extraheader=env_var_http.extraheader fetch --force --tags --prune --prune-tags --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin --depth=1 +a8316d8395ac357bc5708fa00cf81730b1469180:refs/remotes/origin/a8316d8395ac357bc5708fa00cf81730b1469180
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/org/': TCP connection reset by peer
##[error]Git fetch failed with exit code: 128
Finishing: Checkout org.apps@main to s
```

How do I resolve below error:

**fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/org/': TCP connection reset by peer**

Comment: Is this agent configured with proxy or the machine enabled with VPN? If you have ruled out the internet connection issue, have you tried the suggestions in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977206/fatal-read-error-connection-reset-by-peer)? May I know if the issue is reproducible when you run the command `git clone https://github.com/<TheGitHubOrgName>/<TheGitHubRepoName>.git` on that Linux machine directly? You may need to generate a Personal Access Token and use it in place of a password.